# Plotting the convolution of the same probability density function with itself

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, iterators

I would like to compute the integral

$$q_n(x)=\int_{B}^A q_{n-1} (\omega)f(x-\omega)\mathrm{d} \omega,\quad q_1=f,\quad n\geq 1.$$

for a given density function $f$. Basically it is the convolution of a pdf with itself for $n$ times in the range $A$ and $B$. when $n=1$, I simply plot the original pdf $f$, if $n=2$, then I convolve it with itself only once and plot etc..

Eventually I would like to plot the densities $q_n$ for $n=1,2,3..,7$ in the same figure.

My code with the help of some people from this forum is

```
f0[x_] := PDF[NormalDistribution[-2, 2], x]
f1[x_] := PDF[NormalDistribution[2, 2], x]

q[1, B_, A_, f_] := f

q[n_ /; n > 1, B_, A_, f_][x_] := Module[{\[Omega]}, 
tempIntegrate[Evaluate[q[n - 1, B,A, f]][\[Omega]] f[x - \[Omega]], {\[Omega],B, A}]]

p[n_, B_, A_, f_] := 
tempIntegrate[q[n, B, A, f][x], {x, -\[Infinity], B}]+tempIntegrate[q[n, B, A, f][x], {x,A, \[Infinity]}] //. 
{s_ tempIntegrate[b_, a__] :>tempIntegrate[s b, a], 
tempIntegrate[tempIntegrate[b_, a__], c__] :>tempIntegrate[b, a, c]} /. 
tempIntegrate -> NIntegrate
```

I can not

```
Plot[q[2, -2, 2, f0][x],{x,-10,10}]
```

correctly and I cannot see the analytical formulation when I type

```
q[2, B, A, f0][x]
```

Could you please help me? Thank you very much.

EDIT :

My eventual intention was to calculate

$$P[n]=\int_{(-\infty,B)\cup (A,\infty)} q_n (x) \mathrm{d}x$$

and p[2, -2, 2, f0] provides me a numerical value but I am also interested in some analytical values.

To do this I tried to change ->NIntegrate to Integrate but then the code didnt function properly.

Comment: Maybe you are not finished editing yet, but what is your definition of tempIntegrate?

Comment: If you replace tempIntegrate with `Integrate`, then `Plot[q[2, 1, 3, f0][y], {y, 0, 2}]` works for me. Note that `Evaluate` does nothing in your code. `Evaluate` is often used in `Plot` to ignore the fact that `Plot` does not evaluate its first argument. `Integrate` however does not hold any arguments. In addition, the Evaluate would only override this if it would surround the entire first argument. I suggest removing the `Evaluate` :). Note that in the `Plot` code I said that worked for me, the function gets integrated a lot of times. I think that is not necessary

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom I tried your suggestions before but the results which I got was incorrect. Please give me 5 minutes and I get some correct numerical values for comparison.

Comment: 0.5227501319481026` ,  0.2973909442488435` , 0.11261520561472473` ,
0.04211024363961929` , 0.01573950408880347`  are the true values for $p[n, -2, 2, f0]$ for $n=1,...,5$

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom i did your suggestion, removed evaluate and changed tempintegrate to Integrate and eventually p[3, -2, 2, f0] gave me nothing))

Comment: Okido. Unfortunately I have to leave soon. I would have liked to make the improvement that I hint at in my answer. I hope this satisfies your examples, I did not test.

Comment: Okay. Thank I will run your suggestion and let you know about the results. Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at `Convolve`?

Comment: @rm-rf Sorry for the very late reply. Except for the answer which I accepted, the other answers are not giving a correct output for iterations greater than 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this will do what you want

```
ClearAll[q]
q[1, B_, A_, f_] := f
q[n_ /; n > 1, B_, A_, f_] :=
 Block[{\[Omega]},
  q[n, B, A, f] =
   Function[x,
    Evaluate[
     Integrate[
      q[n - 1, B, A, f][\[Omega]] f[x - \[Omega]], {\[Omega], B, A}]]
    ]
  ]
```

Plotting q2 will now be very fast, as Mathematica will evaluate the integral for q2 to a simpler form, even before x is known, which greatly speeds up computation. That is, in this case you do not evaluate an integral for every x you wish to plot.

However, it turns out Mathematica is not able to find a nice expression for q3. We can still plot it, but at every step Mathematica tries to evaluate a difficult integral analytically, so this takes long and is suboptimal. Maybe I can improve it :).

Example:

```
Plot[q[2, 1, 3, f0][x], {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that the definition of q[2,1,3,f0] is now

```
q[2,1,3,f0]

(*output*)
Function[x$,(E^(-(1/16) (4+x$)^2) (-Erf[(2-x$)/4]+Erf[(6-x$)/4]))/(8 Sqrt[\[Pi]])]
```

so that we indeed see that here the Integral has been analytically "solved"/"simplified"/"evaluated".

However, again, this does not work for q3. The definition of that becomes

```
q[3, 1, 3, f0]
(*output in InputForm ;)*)

Function[x$, Integrate[(E^(-(2 + x$ - \[Omega])^2/8 - (4 + \[Omega])^2/16)*
    (-Erf[(2 - \[Omega])/4] + Erf[(6 - \[Omega])/4]))/(16*Sqrt[2]*Pi), {\[Omega], 1, 3}]]
```

where we see that the function Integrate is still present.

Comment: Note that to get values for q4 you have to use the function `N`, that is, write for example `q[4, 1, 3, f0][2] // N`.

Answer (score 5):

There may be a better way to approach this problem. If you transform your function `f[t]` into the frequency domain `ft[w]`, convolution becomes multiplication, and the iterative convolution of `f[t]` with itself becomes raising `ft[w]` to a power. Here is a simple example where

```
f[t_] := Exp[-t^2/2];
ft[w_] := FourierTransform[f[t], t, w]
```

Now you can plot the powers of `ft[w]`:

```
Plot[Table[ft[w]^n, {n, 1, 5, 1}], {w, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

which are the transforms of the time functions. You can return to the time domain by inverse-transforming, for example, at the 5th step,

```
InverseFourierTransform[ft[w]^5, w, t]

E^(-(t^2/10))/Sqrt[5]
```

Of course you can replace this `f[t]` with your `f0[t]` without any problems. Below, the OP asked for how to do this when the range of the function is restricted. This can be handled by truncating the function. Here's a truncated normal distribution:

```
f1[t_, a_, b_] := UnitStep[t - a] UnitStep[b - t] PDF[NormalDistribution[-2, 2], t];
```

This can be transformed (almost) as easily as above:

```
f1t[w_, a_, b_] = FourierTransform[f1[t, a, b], t, w];
Plot[Table[N[Abs[f1t[w, -3, 3]]]^n, {n, 1, 5, 1}], {w, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is not a bad idea but my convolutions is in some prespecified range $A$ and $B$. how can I do in in a parametric way?

Comment: Define your function to be whatever you want in the region A to B, and zero outside. `UnitStep` is one way to do this.

Comment: thank you very much for the edit. I have bigger problem but the idea of frequency domain sounds very interesting, After some progress I will get back to you.

Comment: I dont get the result of inverse Fourier transform

Answer (score 4):

```
con[f_, g_, x_, l_, u_] := 
 Integrate[(f /. x -> x ) (g /. x -> (y - x)), {x, l, u}];
func[u_, ll_, ul_] := 
 Nest[con[#, PDF[NormalDistribution[], x], x, ll, ul] &, 
  PDF[NormalDistribution[], x], u];
```

Using integration limits of -1 and 1:

```
tab = Table[func[j, -1, 1], {j, 5}];
Plot[tab, {y, -3, 3}, PlotLegends -> Range[5]]
```

[image]
gives:

**EDIT**

To allow use of f0[x] and f1[x] and incorporating alternative suggested by bills):

```
q[f_, g_, x_, b_, a_, n_] := 
 Nest[Convolve[#, f (UnitStep[x - b] - UnitStep[x - a]), x, y] &, g, 
  n]
```

Applying to f0[x] (note must put as expression of x not just f0]:

```
qtab = Table[q[f0[x], f0[x], x, -1, 1, j], {j, 5}];
```

and plotting:

```
Plot[qtab, {y, -4, 4}, PlotLegends -> Range[5]]
```

[image]

Comment: It might be easier to use the `Convolve` command, which does more or less what your `con` does.

Comment: @bills thank you for the feedback. `Convolve` uses -Infinity to Infinity as limits of integration (as far as I understand the documentation). I could not find options to alter the limits of integration, hence custom function.

Comment: You can limit the range of integration by changing the function (`Unitstep` for instance) because any given convolution has fixed endpoints. But your custom function is fine too...

Comment: @bills thank you for this, another option  for my future reference

Comment: I am not able to use it in my program. I replaced  PDF[NormalDistribution[] parts with either $f_0$ or $f_0[x]$ and both gave an error. I would like to have a form q[n,B,A,f] for which I can select an $f$ too, for example $f_0$ as given in the question. How one should modify the code?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören sorry...will try to generalize when i get time...and hope will work

Comment: @bills it will be surprising may be but the both codes written above are incorrect.

Comment: NIntegrate[func[2, -2, 2], {y, -\[Infinity], -2}] + 
 NIntegrate[func[2, -2, 2], {y, 2, \[Infinity]}]   gives 0.134642 which should be 0.1126. The second part related to convolution gives also incorrect results because the unit steps are not well defined. they should be applied to the output of convolution. In the current case it is applied in the convolve function. I changed it from the convolve function to the density $f0$ as a multiplicative term like f0:=.... (unit..-unit) and it is still problematic.