# Calculating the recursion at the Fourier domain

Tags: recursion, fourier-analysis

I would like to calculate the following recursion with mathematica 
$$f_n(x)=\int_{B}^{A}f_{n-1}(x-\omega)f(\omega)\mbox{d}\omega\quad\quad f_1(w):=f(w)$$ 
This is simply the convolution of $f$ with itself in the range $(B,A)$. I think it is possible to rewrite this in ordinary convolution form as

$$f_n(x)=\int_{B}^{A}f_{n-1}(x-\omega)f(\omega)\mbox{d}\omega=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{n-1}(x-\omega)f(\omega)1_{\{B<\omega<A\}}\mbox{d}\omega\\=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{n-1}(x-\omega)g(\omega)\mbox{d}\omega\quad\mbox{with}\quad g(\omega)=f(\omega)1_{\{B<\omega<A\}}$$
which says that $f_n$ is obtained by convolving $f_{n-1}$ with $g$

$$f_n=f_{n-1}(*)g$$

this corresponds to multiplication at the Fourier domain

$$F_n=F_{n-1}G$$

For $n=2$ we have $F_2=F_{1}G=FG$. For $n=3$, $F_3=F_{2}G=F_{1}GG=FG^2$, continuing like this we get

$$F_n=F G^{n-1}$$

First of all I wonder if what I have done is correct or is there something missing or incorrect?

Next I wrote a code in mathematica as follows to implement this for $n=3$. I wanted it for all $n$ but it didnt work. Here is the code:

```
Needs["FourierSeries`"]
opts = {Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> None},AccuracyGoal -> 8}
a = 2;
b = -2;
f1[x_] := Evaluate@PDF[NormalDistribution[2, 2], x]
g1[x_] := f1[x]*(UnitStep[x - b]*UnitStep[-x + a])
ff1[u_] = FourierTransform[f1[x], x, u, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}]
gg1[u_] = FourierTransform[g1[x], x, u, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}]
den[x_?NumericQ] := NInverseFourierTransform[ff1[u]*gg1[u]^2, u, x,FourierParameters -> {1, 1}, Evaluate@opts]
NIntegrate[den[x], {x, -8, b}, Evaluate@opts]
0.00463943 - 1.7541*10^-18 I
```

The result should however be $0.00397888$. For $n=2$ namely when

```
den[x_?NumericQ] := NInverseFourierTransform[ff1[u]*gg1[u]^1, u, x,FourierParameters -> {1, 1}, Evaluate@opts]
NIntegrate[den[x], {x, -8, b}, Evaluate@opts]
0.0105702 + 9.00034*10^-18 I
```

I get the correct result..

I am really confused. Can anybody see what is the problem here?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: How is this question different from your previous - and what is wrong with those answers? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33790/1783

Comment: @bill once again the problem is not taking the fourier transform. The problem is that the true results that i get via convolution do not coincide with the results that I get via the recursion at the Fourier domain and I dont know the reason...

Comment: In the code above you have not defined `ff1` or `gg1` so it is not clear what you are trying to do. Why are you loading Needs[`FourierSeries`]? What's wrong with FourierTransform and InverseFourierTransform? And if you are going to do it numerically, then `Fourier` and `InverseFourier` should be the correct commands.

Comment: @bills thanks for the comment. I forgot anyhow **ff1** and **gg1**. I've just edited and included them. FourierTransform is not okay because taking the integral of error function is not an analytic function therefore FourierTransform fails.. thats the reason why I used NFourierTransform. As long as I know Fourier was for discrete data, that is the reason why I chose NFourierTransform:

Comment: Do you have a good reason for writing forms containing `... := Evaluate @ ...`? In general, such forms produce slow-running code. Unless you have said good reason, replace `:=` witth `=`.

Comment: @m_goldberg no i dont have any good reason. I used to use $:=$ do you think it is better to replace all $:=$ with $=$?

Comment: No not all, Not `g1` or `den` which don't have the form `... := Evaluate @ ...`. I recommend you read [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18487/3066).

Comment: @m_goldberg okay i got the point. Thank you very much.